# How to change distance between x-axis.text and x-axis in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

How can I change the distance between axis.text.x in ggplotly. `hjust` and `vjust` change after converting the plot to interactive form.

```
ggplotly (
        ggplot(input,
             aes(x=SubCellType, y = GeneName, colour= ExpressionValue, shape=virus_state)) +
        geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.55, jitter.height = 0.16, dodge.width = 0.1), size=2, stroke = 1.5, alpha = 0.7) +
        facet_grid(~ CellType, scales = "free_x")+
        theme_bw() + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13, color = "black", angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1,family="serif"),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13, color = "#004e00", face = "italic",family="serif"))
    )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change the distance between axis.text.x"?  You want to change the distance between the axis and the tick-mark labels?  If so, do you want it to be more or less than it currently is?  It would be useful to have a reproducible example and the desired output.